# How to allow or deny specific files to CD using TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are using TFS2018 version and implementing CI/CD. I need to deploy only specific files to the target environment. How to achieve this?

Suppose, i have 100 files in my TFS and my requirement is to deploy only 80 files and hold back 20 specific files from deployment[CD], this is project specific. I'm not sure on which TFS task or script in release pipeline has got this capability.

Any appropriate suggestion is welcome and appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can define a ***build pipeline*** to copy the files you need and publish **artifacts** using the tasks below.

[image]

And then you can define a ***release pipeline*** to consume and deploy those artifacts to deployment targets. Azure Pipelines releases can deploy artifacts that are produced by Azure Pipelines build.

Comment: In `Copy Files to` task how to define only the specific files to be copied/omitted? Please suggest

Comment: You can use files path or match patterns. More details, please check `Contents` argument in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#arguments. And check File matching patterns reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops

Comment: Its some what helpful.Still trying on it. Couldn't get how to specify on excluding unnecessary files. If you have any script...it could be very helpful

Comment: Leading `!` changes the meaning of an include pattern to exclude. You may check the examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#examples.